# PHP - Best Practise - Website Templates

Tags: php, templates

I just wanted to see if the way I am constructing my website templates was the best and most dynamic way of doing it. Currently I have my website playout however for the areas that I want the content to change I use the following code.

```
<? 
 if (preg_match("/\W/",$page) || !file_exists("../$page.html")) {
  include("../home.html");
 }
 else {
  include("../$page.html");
 }
?>
```

The navigation then links to that page by saying something like,

```
<a href="index.php?page=about">About</a>
```

Is this the best way to construct a template using PHP or are there better ways? Thankyou for the help.

Comment: This is not templating. Also, theres a lot of ways to build up a website and this is just one of them. This question will only solicite debate.

Comment: In lesser forums a question like this would solicit debate, but most of us here are aware that there's no "best" way to do anything. Only _different ways_ or _completely wrong ways_. Nevertheless, this question doesn't have a single "correct" answer so I flagged it as not constructive. I hope this doesn't keep you from asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no best or most dynamic way of creating website templates.

All you can do is learn from experience and others.

Your code is one way to switch between templates. Some immediate improvements could be:

- Use && instead of || because of short circuiting properties of the AND
  operator. If the page does not match then there is no need to do the
  file check
- Use a array lookup table to map page value to filename template (e.g. 'home'->'homepage.html' etc.), mainly this helps in preventing serious     exploits where external input is used for file paths.
- Don't file check because why have a link with a non existent template?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing from scratch like this (and IMO not so beautiful or dynamic as well), you better take a look at how frameworks do it. Most frameworks have (good, beautiful, dynamic, scalable, whatever) templating mechanism, both still in pure PHP or using 3rd party engine.